# How Can I Access Android Phone Camera With gozxing

Tags: go, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have been trying to develop an application to read barcodes and QR codes for a while and I found gozxing but I could not find how to access the camera.

I try to apply the scanning logic to this code down below

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/theme"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func makeUI(tabs *container.AppTabs) *fyne.Container {
    return container.New(layout.NewGridLayout(1),
        tabs)
}

func makeUI2(entry *widget.Entry, button *widget.Button) *fyne.Container {
    return container.New(layout.NewVBoxLayout(),
        entry,
        container.NewVBox(
            button,
        ),
    )
}

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("Kütüphane")
    myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(300, 400))

    // db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "kutuphane.db")
    // defer db.Close()
    // if err != nil {
    //  log.Fatal(err)
    // }

    input := widget.NewEntry()
    input.SetPlaceHolder("Kitap Numarasını Girin")

    tabs := container.NewAppTabs(
        container.NewTabItemWithIcon("Ana Sayfa", theme.HomeIcon(), container.NewVBox(widget.NewButton("Barkodu Okut", func() {
            w2 := myApp.NewWindow("Kütüphane")
            w2.Resize(fyne.NewSize(200, 300))
            w2.SetContent(makeUI2(input, widget.NewButton("Kaydet", func() {

            })))
            w2.Show()
            log.Print("Clicked")
        }))),
        container.NewTabItem("Ayarlar", container.NewVBox()),
        container.NewTabItem("Aktifler", container.NewVBox()),
    )
    tabs.SetTabLocation(container.TabLocationBottom)

    myWindow.SetContent(makeUI(tabs))

    myWindow.Show()
    myApp.Run()
}
```

I expected it to open and work properly, but I couldn't because I didn't understand it.
If it doesn't work, I can even do it with C code.